# configured http.proxy works for git but not for jgit

Tags: git, jgit

Lets show the --global .gitconfig first, as git and as jgit sees it!!!
from a DOS window as well as from a Cgywin window

```
E:\> git config --list --global
http.auth.preference=Basic
user.name=Josef Stadelmann
user.email=josef.stadelmann@axa-winterthur.ch
http.proxy=http://C770817:MyPassword@bcproxyserver.ch.winterthur.com:8080

E:\>
```

Now lets look from a Cygwin Window with JGit

```
$ jgit config --list --global
http.auth.preference=Basic
user.email=josef.stadelmann@axa-winterthur.ch
user.name=Josef Stadelmann
http.proxy=http://C770817:MyPassword@bcproxyserver.ch.winterthur.com:8080
```

WE CAN SEE THE SAME CONFIGURATION
THEN 
WHY DOES

```
C770817@C036357 ~
$ jgit ls-remote https://github.com/stadelma/HelloWorld.git
fatal: Connection time out: github.com
fatal: https://github.com/stadelma/HelloWorld.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
```

timeout BUT

```
C770817@C036357 ~
$ git ls-remote http://github.com/stadelma/HelloWorld.git
35f375cb64208b64ed499c2a47727dfcd8813dea        HEAD
35f375cb64208b64ed499c2a47727dfcd8813dea        refs/heads/master

C770817@C036357 ~
$
```

works properly reading the same .gitconfig at

```
/cygdrive/e/mingw/home/.gitconfig
```

????

Any advise welcome - OR - shall I just start debugging jgit ?

Josef

Answer (score 3):

You can try and see if an *environment variable* would work better, with java option like:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxyhosturl
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=”localhost|mybambooserverurl”
```

As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884879/6309):

- `Dhttp.proxyHost` – proxy IP address
- `Dhttp.proxyPort` – proxy port
- `Dhttp.proxyUser` – user name if HTTP-proxy authentication required;
- `Dhttp.proxyPassword` – user password if HTTP-proxy authentication required.